# How to display arrow in GridView on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView where I am displaying some files from a folder. I was able to add the up and the down arrow for the two column headers to update based on the sorting. The arrow shows up after I click on the column header twice.

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No PDF was generated" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="File Name" SortExpression="FileName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" HeaderText="File Modified Date" SortExpression="FileDate" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' OnClick="DownloadFile" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" Text="View in Browser" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' OnClientClick="window.document.forms[0].target='blank';" runat="server" OnClick="ViewFile" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Page_Load:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) //loaded first time...
{
    //MessageBox.Show("Fires from a PAGE REFRESH or FIRST VISIT");
    BindData();
}
```

Supporting Functions:

```
protected void BindData()
{
    try
    {
        filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\PDFGenerate");
        files = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath).ToString()));

        }
        //GridView1.DataSource = files;
        //GridView1.DataBind();
        Session["fileData"] = files;
        Sort(files, SortDirection.Descending);
    }
    catch (Exception ce)
    {
    }
    //MessageBox.Show(files.Count() + ""); // displays the count for the files being displayed
}
public void Sort(IList<ListItem> items, SortDirection direction)
{
    var dataTable = ToDataTable(items);
    var dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
    dataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Value",
        direction == SortDirection.Ascending ? "ASC" : "DESC");
    GridView1.DataSource = dataView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
public DataTable ToDataTable(IList<ListItem> data)
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Text", typeof(string));

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        var row = table.NewRow();
        row["Value"] = item.Value;
        row["Text"] = item.Text;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return table;
}
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        LinkButton lbSort;
        Image imgArrow;

        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            if (cell.HasControls())
            {
                lbSort = (LinkButton)cell.Controls[0];
                imgArrow = new Image();

                if (ViewState["SortColumn"] != null)
                {
                    if (lbSort.CommandArgument == ViewState["SortColumn"].ToString())
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["SortColumnDirection"]) == (int)SortDirection.Ascending)
                        {
                            imgArrow.ImageUrl = "down.png";
                            //MessageBox.Show("UP");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            imgArrow.ImageUrl = "up.png";
                            //MessageBox.Show("DOWN");
                        }
                        cell.Controls.Add(imgArrow);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void GridView1_Sorting(object server, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    string strSortExpression = e.SortExpression;
    MessageBox.Show(e.SortExpression.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(e.SortDirection.ToString());
    switch (strSortExpression)
    {
        case "FileName":
            if (e.SortExpression == (string)ViewState["SortColumn"])
            {
                // We are resorting the same column, so flip the sort direction
                e.SortDirection =
                    ((SortDirection)ViewState["SortColumnDirection"] == SortDirection.Ascending) ?
                    SortDirection.Descending : SortDirection.Ascending;
            }
            Sort2((IList<ListItem>)Session["fileData"], e.SortDirection, "filename");
            ViewState["SortColumn"] = e.SortExpression;
            ViewState["SortColumnDirection"] = e.SortDirection;
            break;
        case "FileDate":
            if (e.SortExpression == (string)ViewState["SortColumn"])
            {
                // We are resorting the same column, so flip the sort direction
                e.SortDirection =
                    ((SortDirection)ViewState["SortColumnDirection"] == SortDirection.Ascending) ?
                    SortDirection.Descending : SortDirection.Ascending;
            }
            Sort2((IList<ListItem>)Session["fileData"], e.SortDirection, "filedate");
            ViewState["SortColumn"] = e.SortExpression;
            ViewState["SortColumnDirection"] = e.SortDirection;
            break;
    }
}
public void Sort2(IList<ListItem> items, SortDirection direction, string type)
{
    var dataTable = ToDataTable(items);
    var dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
    switch (type)
    {
        case "filename":
            dataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Text",
                direction == SortDirection.Ascending ? "ASC" : "DESC");
            GridView1.DataSource = dataView;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            break;
        case "filedate":
            dataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Value",
                direction == SortDirection.Ascending ? "ASC" : "DESC");
            GridView1.DataSource = dataView;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            break;
    }
}
```

- How can I make it so the arrow shows up when the page loads? (I am
  sorting by file modified date on page load)
- Why the arrow takes two clicks on the respective header to show up? (although the sorting is correct the arrow is shown wrong the first click on a different header column, and needs one extra click for the image to be shown correctly)
  Example:

[image]

Comment: where are you setting ViewState["SortColumn"] ??

Comment: Updated my question with the codes where I define it.

Comment: Code for down arrow is &#8595;  and up arrow is: &#8593; Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on page load you are not getting the image because

`ViewState["SortColumn"]` is null which is set in `GridView_Sorting` function (which is not called on page_load)

set it to a default value

again you are not able to set the image on first sort click because **RowCreated** is called before you **GridView_Sorting** function

so the next time when you click it row_created finds the value and sets the image

Comment: How do I set the default value?

Comment: set ViewState["SortColumn"] = "FileName"; before GridView1.DataBind(); line in Sort(IList<ListItem> items, SortDirection direction) function

Comment: That displays the arrow but now I get a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error here: `e.SortDirection =
      ((SortDirection)ViewState["SortColumnDirection"] == SortDirection.Ascending) ?
      SortDirection.Descending : SortDirection.Ascending;` inside the Sorting function for `case "FileName"`.

Comment: check the value for ViewState["SortColumnDirection"] before casting it to SortDirection

Comment: If I click on another column and come back to the column that's throwing the error, it works fine.

Comment: I tried to add `ViewState["SortColumnDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;` with the code you suggested in earlier comment. but the table isn't sorted correctly when the page loads.

Comment: just setting a value in viewstate wont change your sorting order, you have to bind the grid with that sort expression and direction

Comment: I know what was happening, I sorted by the second column but was trying to update it and that's why I was having the issue.

Comment: Now when the second column is sorted from ASC to DESC, I have to click on it twice for it change from DESC to ASC, wonder why

Comment: I can post what I have now and you can take a look? :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56563/discussion-between-karthik-ganesan-and-searchforknowledge).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I had to switch the ASC and DESC inside the Sort2 function for it to work properly.